Execute Prepared Statement in a Stored Procedure in Informix
I am using Informix 12.10 on most of my systems, and I am trying to run this using dbaccess on a Windows server.  I am trying to understand how to work with stored procedures and prepared statements.  The code below is an example of what I am trying to do.
drop procedure if exists findIdReferences;
create procedure "uqed".findIdReferences(
    u_idnum like persons.idnum
)
    define my_count integer;
    
    define my_tablename like systables.tabname;
    define my_stmt lvarchar(2250);

    drop table if exists idnumTableSearch;
    create table idnumTableSearch (
        tableName   char(256) not null,
        count       integer not null
    );

    foreach 
        SELECT tabname
        into my_tablename
        FROM systables a, syscolumns b 
        WHERE a.tabid = b.tabid 
            and colname = "idnum"

        -- might be able to use a prepared statement here instead.
        let my_stmt = "select count(*) from " || trim(my_tablename) || " where idnum = " || u_idnum || ";";

        prepare p from my_stmt;
        execute p into my_count;

        if (my_count > 0) then
            insert into idnumTableSearch (tableName, count)
            values (my_tablename, count);
        end if

    end foreach;

    foreach
        select tableName, count
        into my_tablename, my_count
        from idnumTableSearch
        
        return my_tablename, mycount with resume;
    end foreach;
        
    drop table if exists idnumTableSearch;
end procedure;

I am getting a 201: A syntax error has occurred with the statement execute p into my_count.  According to the documentation I found, that should work for a statement that just returns 1 row.  Unfortunately, I am getting a syntax error on the execute.  I don't see, or understand, what I am doing wrong with that execute statement.  In C/C++ using ODBC, I could prepare the statement and bind the parameters to variables.
UPDATE:
The documentation on this page says:

Tip: To execute a singleton SELECT, the EXECUTE...INTO statement is more efficient than using the DECLARE, OPEN, and FETCH statements.

Unfortunately, I have not gotten this to work properly.

You need to declare a cursor, open, fetch and close it.  And free both the statement and the cursor.

I knew about doing that process of using a cursor, but in the documentation, it said this was supposed to be possible.

There are 2 parts in the Informix documentation. One part is about the ESQL/C API and another is about the SPL API. They are similar but not equal. The documentation you pointed out is for ESQL/C. It might not apply to SPL's .

I'm puzzled that I cannot find documentation about dynamic SQL in SPL in either the 12.10 or 14.10 versions.  I suppose I must be missing something obvious.

Can't find anything in the documentation ( does not mean it is not there, just that I can't find it ) about EXECUTE INTO being valid on a SPL context ( the ones I found are specific for EXECUTE FUNCTION or EXECUTE PROCEDURE ). The alternative is using a cursor with the DECLARE,OPEN.FETCH statements.

@JonathanLeffler, if you post your comment as an answer, I will except it as the answer.  I ended up going with that option anyways.  A prepared statement with a place holder would not have helped.  I wanted to change the table each time because I was search for specific data in specific columns across all tables.  I ended up building a select each time to use with the cursor.  The page I linked above is from the "Client Software Development Kit, Version 4.10" for 12.10.  Google and here seem to be more reliable than the documentation.  Thanks for the responses everyone.

There is documentation on using DECLARE in SPL (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statement-declaring-dynamic-cursor-in-spl-routine).  The EXECUTE statement doesn't have a corresponding sub-section.  I'm going to report that as a documentation bug — it may take some time to get it fixed.

The documentation for dynamic SQL in SPL is hit and miss.
There is documentation on using DECLARE in SPL (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statement-declaring-dynamic-cursor-in-spl-routine).  The EXECUTE statement doesn't have a corresponding sub-section and the page on EXECUTE INTO is officially for ESQL/C, not SPL.  I'm planning to report this as a documentation bug.
Anyway, the tried and trusted method is to use:

PREPARE to prepare the statement
DECLARE to declare a cursor for the statement
OPEN to open the cursor
FETCH to collect values, possibly in a loop, possibly with a RETURN … WITH RESUME
CLOSE the cursor
FREE the cursor
FREE the statement


It seems like all the Informix documentation is hit or miss.  Thanks again for you help.
